# web request timeout handling?

Tags: c#, error-handling, timeout, webrequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 20000;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Do something with result
}
```

In the above example I have a timeout defined, if it happens to hit the timeout how would I know, the result would be empty ?

Do I receive any reponse types ?

How can I make sure I got timed out ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`GetResponse()` would throw a [`WebException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx). It's simple to test *exactly* what happens though - set the timeout to 1ms and try to hit anything which takes a while to come back.

In fact, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse.aspx) states this explicitly:

> If the timeout period expires before the resource can be returned, a WebException is thrown.

Comment: thanks that was what I was looking for I was not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) call will throw a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) when;

```
Abort was previously called.    
-or-    
The time-out period for the request expired.
-or-    
An error occurred while processing the request.
```

Catch this exception.

I used to just pull my network cable out to test this sort of thing although you could be more elegant and use a proxy tool and block that particular request.

Comment: Thanks, `The time-out period for the request expired.` that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using [HTTPWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx).  It has a status code that tells you that information and more.  HTTPWebResponse is a descendant of WebResponse.